# Find value lies between key in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this in php-

```
$array=array
(
    "0.00" => 1,
    "50.00" => 3,
    "75.00" => 2,
    "100.00" => 3,
    "120.00" => 1,
    "180.00" => 5,
    "200.00" => 6,
    "210.00" => 4,
    "220.00" => 2,
    "300.00" => 1,
    "500.00" => 7
);
```

I have to find values between 0-100 and 100-200, so my new array should look like this-

```
array{
  "0-100" => 9, // total values between 0 to 100 including value of 0 and 100
  "100-200" => 15,  // total values between 100 to 200 including value of 100 and 200 
  "200-300" => 13,  // same way
  "300-500" => 8  //same way
}
```

How can I make this array.?

Comment: And the problem/question is? (UPDATE: I guess try with some code; As long as you didn't tried something you can't fail)

Comment: A little bit of work with [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) should do this.... but you do realise that you're actually overlapping your ranges?

Comment: Your keys conveniently match the range boundaries you are looking for, is that always the case? And should they go with the previous, the next or both? Also note that `200` is not necessarily the same as `200.00`

Comment: What output or which method are you expected to use?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the use of `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` requires PHP >=5.6.0

```
$array=[
    "0.00" => 1,
    "50.00" => 3,
    "75.00" => 2,
    "100.00" => 3,
    "120.00" => 1,
    "180.00" => 5,
    "200.00" => 6,
    "210.00" => 4,
    "220.00" => 2,
    "300.00" => 1,
    "500.00" => 7
];

function filtered($array, $min, $max) {
    return array_sum(
        array_filter(
            $array,
            function($key) use ($min, $max) {
                return (($key >= $min) && ($key <= $max));
            },
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
        )
    );
}

$newArray = [
    '0-100' => filtered($array, 0, 100),
    '100-200' => filtered($array, 100, 200),
    '200-300' => filtered($array, 200, 300),
    '300-400' => filtered($array, 300, 400),
];

var_dump($newArray);
```

**EDIT**

If you're not using PHP >= 5.6.0, then you can use

```
function filtered($array, $min, $max) {
    return array_sum(
        array_intersect_key(
            $array,
            array_flip(
                array_filter(
                    array_keys($array),
                    function($key) use ($min, $max) {
                        return (($key >= $min) && ($key <= $max));
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

instead